# Find all records which does not exist in table sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

ٰI am working on a dictionary application based on php and sqlite. I want to make an option through which user can validate list of words which does not exits in database. I wonder if there is anyway I can validate the list in a single query.

**Edit**
Following is table structure

```
word | definition
word 1 | definition 1
word 2 | definition 2
word 3 | definition 3
```

[image: Structure]

Comment: Please give sample data. Your database contains a list of words, is that right? And you want to check if some given word exists in the database?

Comment: Yes, my database contains list of words. No I do not want to check if some given word exists in the database. I want to check, from a given list, which words does not exists in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join input list to the target table/column and keep rows having NULL in the fields from the "words" table.

```sql
WITH
    query_input(word) AS (
        VALUES ('word 1'), ('word 2'), ('word 0'), ('word 3'), ('word 5')
    ),
    -- Remove this CTE when querying against your db.
    dict(id, word, definition) AS (
        VALUES
            (1, 'word 1', 'definition 1'),
            (2, 'word 2', 'definition 2'),
            (3, 'word 3', 'definition 3')
    ),
    new_words AS (
        SELECT query_input.*
        FROM query_input
        LEFT JOIN dict ON query_input.word = dict.word
        WHERE dict.id IS NULL
    )
SELECT * FROM new_words;
```